# sql left join only when left column can be a number

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a couple of tables (not mine), and want to left join the data. The problem is the left table's column is sometimes a number and sometimes a string. The right table's column is always a number. SQL errors out when the left column can't be converted.

How can I join the columns whenever possible?

Comment: 1) Cast number to string and then do compare. 2) write a subquery to return only those values that are numeric and join then union in those that are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the on clause so the A value is listed first so engine tries to implicitly cast to string(A's datatype) instead of int (B's data type)

```
SELECT a.*, B.*
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B 
-- on B.AID=A.ID   --Instead of B.AID= A.ID
  on A.ID = B.AID
```

Don't let the engine do the implicit casting, forcibly cast B values to string...

Casting number to string...

```
SELECT a.*, B.*
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B 
 on trim(A.ID) = cast(B.AID as varchar(100))
```

or

join only when A is numeric and union in rest of A that isn't.  Note: you may have to spell out the values from B in lieu of the join below.

```
SELECT a.*, B.*
FROM (SELECT * from A where isNumeric(ID)) A
LEFT JOIN B 
 on A.ID = cast(B.AID as varchar(100))
UNION
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * From B where 1 =0)
WHERE not isNumeric(ID)
```

Comment: I hadn't realized order to be important in a join, or that you can cast in the on clause. Very informative, thanks.

Comment: As far as I know the engine will always attempt to cast to the data type first encountered (the one on the left of the expression) when data types differ.